# Can a property name and a method name be same in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, class, methods, properties

I have a class which contains a property:

```
public bool IsMandatory {get;set;}
```

Now I am adding a method `IsMandatory(string str)`.

```
public bool IsMandatory(string str)
{
  //return false;
  //return true;
}
```

I am getting a compile time error that

> *the type already contains a definition for 'IsMandatory'*

Can't a method name and property name be same in C# ? We use a method and property in different way, why is this giving compile error ?

Comment: If the compiler has told you you can't, then what are actually asking? Why you can't?

Comment: @TimRogers, yes I am asking why we can't ?

Comment: how would it know which one you meant to call?

Comment: There are programming languages that do allow this sort of thing and they're horrible to use.  Be thankful the C# compiler has stopped you from adopting bad practice.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a compiler error because it would cause confusion if the names could be the same. There are some cases where ambiguity could result - for example, when using Action delegates and so on, where methods do not need to have parenthesis, and when using `var`.

Comment: The compiler can happily distinguish between the overloaded methods `Set_IsMandatory(bool value)` and `Set_IsMandatory(string value)`, and if properties are just [syntactic sugar for the getter and setter methods](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/62395/59429) then it would seem reasonable to allow methods and properties to share the same name as long as the resulting signatures were different?  I do not see the "confusion" you mention, perhaps you might consider expanding on your answer to help me understand?

Comment: @Ben Consider a property, `P` that returns a delegate for a method that takes one parameter. Now consider having, in the same class, a method called `P` that takes one parameter of the same kind. If you were to write `instance.P(x)` it would be ambiguous as to whether you are calling the method `P` or calling a delegate via the property `P`.

Answer (score 0):

In short: It is just not allowed. Member names (field, property, and method) must be
unique.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why and when. E.g. method overloading is allowed.